# Does kissing/touching a non-spouse female break the fast?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, sawm, ramadan, relationships

I understand that it is wrong to kiss or touch a woman that is not your lawful spouse but my question is : does it break the fast to touch, kiss, or do any non sexual acts with her ?

Answer (score 0):

Kissing doesn't break the fast, although if you fear of discharging or something else then it's not good todo in ramazan because in that case your fast will break.
However if you can control yourself into only kissing that allowed, but still Magroh.